# Manage file type or application defaults in Android 8

Tags: 8.0-oreo, default-applications

I am using [Solid File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2) to browse my files. Each time I tap an image, it is opened in Google's [Photos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos&hl=en_US). I would like to know where this relation is defined in my Android 8.0 and how can I change it (i.e. should I modify  defaults of Solid File Explorer or Google Photos or both)?

I am asking, because both applications defaults' settings doesn't suggest such relation exists:

[image]

I.e. Solid File Explorer doesn't open anything by default and Photos opens only some links and no file types. And the "*Clear defaults*" button is disabled in both cases. So, I am a little bit stumbled on how does my Android 8.0 know that it should open images in Photos and how can I change it.

Both questions that I've read so far ([this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14265/20449) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14882/20449)) are seven years old and covers a very old version of Android. So brings no help here.

Comment: Related: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203923/218526) is how a file is opened on Android